# Autoclose Laravel Blade directives in PhpStorm not working

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, laravel-blade, phpstorm-2019

I am trying to get Blade directives to automatically close the tags (so typing `@if` should automatically create the closing `@endif` tag and cursor should move one line down with a tab space, as it does for normal PHP if tag). But all I am getting is (no closing tag).

[image]

I have imported the Laravel Live template settings from: https://github.com/koomai/phpstorm-laravel-live-templates and also followed steps from here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/auto-close-directives-in-phpstorm

My Live Template settings: (I have tried enabling the 'Reformat according to style' checkbox, doesn't work):
[image]

I'm using PhpStorm 2019.2 on Mac Mojave.

---

**UPDATED:**

@if Live Template (works as expected, after pressing Tab):

[image]

Correct behaviour: tag is automatically closed:
[image]

---

@foreach Live Template (not working, I've tried using $START$ instead of $USERS$ as well, no luck):

[image]

When I type up until @fore: get following pop up:
[image]

Ok I just noticed as doing this, there are TWO @foreach's, the 2nd one works as expected. Need to figure out how to remove the first definition (I have disabled the Laravel plugin I have installed but that hasn't removed it) ...

Comment: So how do you type your stuff? What keys do you press? In particular: what do you press after typing `@if`. Some small screencast/gif will be helpfull here

Comment: hi @LazyOne I type '\@i' then \@if comes up then I type space and open bracket ' (' it then creates a close bracket and cursor goes to middle of two brackets, so I then have '\@if ([cursor])' ... then I type my condition (in this case just 'true' for testing). I'm expecting when I go to (after) closing bracket and press Enter, the \@endif should appear and cursor should indent a tab (note: please ignore the \ before at signs, SO won't let me post it otherwise think I am mentioning people)

Comment: You need to type `@if` and then press `TAB` -- as simple as that. `TAB` is your expand key for Live Templates. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-live-templates.html  P.S. *"note: please ignore the \ before at signs..."* Use back tick to denote start/end of "inline code sample" -- it works well for such usages here in the comments.

Comment: thanks @LazyOne ok so it's working for `@if` (tab works thanks) but not for `@foreach` ... exact same settings (facepalm)

Comment: Please show how `@foreach` Live Template is defined + how Code Completion popup looks after you finished typing `@foreach` (before hitting Tab). I'm just not using those custom Live Templates myself so cannot quick test it here.

Comment: The first one (that has `fore` part in blue) is an actual Blade tag completion (provided by PHP plugin itself/Blade support part) -- it will complete the tag itself (just like any keyword/function name etc). The 2nd one (that has `@fore` part in blue and includes `@` symbol as well) is an actual Live Template and you need that one. *You need to type the whole abbreviation in order to expand it* (otherwise how to know that you meant exactly that). **Possible workaround:** edit that Live Template and make abbreviation shorter (e.g. make it `@fore` only)

Comment: thanks @LazyOne. Yeah I've tried disabling the blade (bundled) plugin, but it basically removes all blade (syntax highlighting, etc support which is not good). Do you know if it's possible to remove specific directives from that plugin/in PhpStorm? Hmm yeh maybe making shorter abbreviations is not bad, `@fe` posssibly. Would be ideal to just have the Blade Live template abbreviations take priority over other autocompletes (such as blade plugin's)

Comment: No, you cannot remove standard tags from completion. It's like asking "I do not use flex/css grid -- I'm using floating divs for everything and need to get rid of that modern stuff..." -- while this can make sense to some individuals/specific cases but overall (vast majority) it's not. **Shorten your Live Templates to better suit your needs/typing habits.**

Comment: thanks @LazyOne for the help much appreciated